# Creating fields with a single instance per thread with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static

I am trying to parallelize a bit of code which makes use of static fields within a "Constants" class.  The code at the moment essentially looks like this

```
public class myClass{

    public class Constants{
          public static int constant;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
          for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++){
              Constants.constant = i;
              System.out.println(Constants.constant/2);
          }
    }
}
```

Obviously the code within the loop is much more heavily dependent on the Constant class, which itself is much more complex. What I'd like to do is create a thread for each iteration of the loop and do said computations separately, all the while controlling the number of threads (right now I'm using a simple semaphore). 
Now obviously in the above code, the Constants class is shared between threads and thus cannot be updated by each thread without being updated for all of them.

So my question is : is there anyway to make my Constants class be able to have an instance for each thread, all the while being able to access its fields in a static manner  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a thead-local: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html . It's a good thing to use. However, as Affe points out, you can't use that with your code as is, because there's just one instance of the class and its static members (per classloader). If your Constants class is something that you can build several several copies of in parallel and then merge them together later, you should make Constants.constant an instance variable by removing "static". Then create a thread-local in myClass like so:

```java
private ThreadLocal<Constants> constants = new ThreadLocal<Constants> {  
    @Override protected Integer initialValue() {  
        return nextId.getAndIncrement();  
    }  
}
```

Once your threads are done updating their local object, they can stick them into a shared ArrayBlockingQueue. Your main thread can dequeue them all and merge them as you desire.

Another thing to note is that you may want to use a thread pool executor instead of one thread per iteration of the loop, if you will have a variable number of iterations, possibly many, but you don't want that many threads. (Thread creation is costly and many concurrent threads eat memory and OS scheduling resources.)

Comment: Not really.  If he stores the value in a static field, there is still only ever one value per class-loader.

Comment: Looking into ThreadLocal; basically each iteration takes so much resources it completely eats up the vcpu it's on so I really only need a thread per vcpu (approx). So there will only be few threads running at a time and given the runtime & memory usage of each iteration, the overhead will be negligible.

Comment: I suppose the *field* could be changed to `ThreadLocal<Integer>` and work.  Although the whole notion of a class named Constants that needs to be refactored so values can be edited hurts my head :)

Comment: Basically each iteration goes through a dataset (from a txt file), computes constants relevant to this dataset and uses them to do stuff requiring a large number of classes, most of which use said constants. So I could just pass an instance of Constants to each other class, but that seems clunky.

Comment: Well, if you have different sets of constants, then surely having one Constants object per set is the _right_ thing, no? But we're detracting from the original point of parallelization. I think what isn't clear is the benefit of using multiple threads, and namely how many. If you are mainly reading from files, then you will be bound by the speed of your disk, which is much slower than the CPU. One thread will be sufficient then. If you want to do some heavy computation from the data loaded in the files then you can use a thread pool with number of threads = number of cores.

Comment: I didn't want to go into details but I'm fairly certain parallelizing is the solution to my problem ; the txt reading isn't the time consuming part, its the calculations that follow. I'm running a very calculation-heavy machine learning algorithm which takes up to a dozen of minutes to run for the data of each txt file ; I have about 1000 files. Eitherway it's besides the point.

Comment: That's interesting. Then you definitely want number of threads = number of cores.